# c++ initializing a default value for a c-style string in dynamic memory

Tags: c++

So in c++ a normal c-style string can be initiated like this:

```
char cString[] = "my string";
```

How can I do the same thing using dynamic memory?

Why doesn't this work?

```
char *charPtr; 

charPtr = new char("make this the value of the c string");
```

Comment: `std::string str = "make this the value of the c string";` If for some reason you insist on C string (despite tagging your question C++), see `strcpy`

Comment: Char is a single  character. A string literal is an array of chars. The fact that they are mismatched types is the problem.A string literal is also **not** dynamic memory.

Comment: because `new X` means: create an instance of `X` on heap (actually, free store). In this case it would allocate a single `char` and you cant squeeze a string in it

Answer (score 0):

You can't just initialize a c-style string like that.
First of all you need a pointer, that points to the beginning of the string. Then need to allocate enough memory to hold that string, which is the number of characters + the terminating '\0'. You should include cstring header, for strlen and strcpy. At last you need to copy the string to the memory block.

```
   char *str; //pointer to string
   str = new char[strlen("The string to copy")+1]; //allocate memory 
   //strlen returns the number of charaters of a string exluding the '\0', so we need to add 1
   //either use a string constant, or another cstyle string, or input the length manually
   strcopy(str, "The string to copy");//strcpy copies the content of the string constant to str
   //be sure to set the last element of the string to '\0'
   str[strlen(str)] = 0; // or '\0'
   //if str has 5 char it returns 4 because the last is \0
   //but the array goes from 0 to 4, so 4 is the last element
```

And dont forget to use delete [ ] str; if you get rid of the string!